# Show what the user typed in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have a code and I want that after the user type something in the `textfield` and press enter, what he typed appears on the screen. But I'm not being able to do that, I'd like some help here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tasks for the day</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

alert("When you have finished your task you only have to click on it.");

$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) {

}
});

function showMsg(){
 var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  document.getElementById('userMsg').innerHTML = userInput;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tasks to do</h1>

<p>Type what you need to do:</p>

<input type="input" id="userInput" onkeyup=showMsg() value="" />
<p id="userMsg"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried the code, its working. Whats the exact problem here? Is it you want when they press enter to clear everything on the screen except the value?

Comment: When the user types something in the box, he will press enter. When he press enter I want that what the typed be showed in the screen.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/v58ugsg5/

Comment: Yes, like this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but, it only adds one value to the screen, to put more than one, do I need to create an array?

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if you wanted something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only adds one value to the screen, to put more than one, do I need
>   to create an array

1. You had the main components working. Namely, you were updating the screen. To have it update only on `enter`, simply put the code in the `keypress` handler
2. To append the value to the screen(in the case of more than one `enter`), concatenate the current `innerHTML` with the value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});

$('#userInput').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var innerHTML = document.getElementById('userMsg').innerHTML;
    innerHTML = innerHTML || '';
    document.getElementById('userMsg').innerHTML += innerHTML + userInput;
  }
});
```

```html
<title>Tasks for the day</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Tasks to do</h1>

<p>Type what you need to do:</p>

<input type="input" id="userInput" onkeyup=showMsg() value="" />
<p id="userMsg"></p>
```